# ¿Cómo puedo borrar contenido de capa con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5, funciones

Intenté hacerlo con una función pero me genera un error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("eliminar");
boton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = ""; 
},false)
```

```html
<div id="micapa">Contenido de prueba <br/> <img src="logo.png"/> <br/> Fin del contenido de prueba </div> Este solo es una prueba <button id="eliminar" onclick="function()">Eliminar Contendio</button>
```

Contenedor es quién esta almacenando toda mi información de la página.

Comment: ¿Qué error le genera ? a simple vista no parece tener errores en el código de su pregunta.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null me resulta es error

Comment: Podría añadir el código `HTML` ?  tiene un elemento con id eliminar?  [su código funciona con un supuesto html](https://repl.it/LobI)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ejemplo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="micapa">Contenido de prueba
  <br/>
  <img src="logo.png"/>
  <br/>
  Fin del contenido de prueba
  </div>
  Este solo es una prueba

<button id="eliminar" onclick="function()">Eliminar Contendio</button>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si añade un `listener` desde `Js` para el evento `click` del botón no hace falta añadir el atributo en la etiqueta `onclick=""` solo debería hacerse una sola vez , recomendación desde `Js` bastará. `boton.addEventListener("...`

El atributo `onclick` espera que se pase el nombre de una función o directamente el código `JS` y en su código hace una llamada a `function` que es una palabra reservada de `Js` lo cuál es incorrecto. No podrá llamar a una función anónima sin un identificador *(si es lo que pretendía hacer)*

No existe ningún elemento con `id` contenedor por lo cuál el `document.getElementById("contenedor")` devuelve `null` y no  tendrá ni métodos ni propiedades como `innerHTML`

**Código final**

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("eliminar");
boton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = ""; 
},false)
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">Contenido de prueba Fin del contenido de prueba Este solo es una prueba </div> 
<button id="eliminar" >Eliminar Contendio</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy buena tu aclaración y la tomaré en cuenta lo que me has dicho. Saludos